# API Output Styling

Tags: php, css, api, joomla

I hate to ask but I've searched all over the internet trying to figure this out.

So I get the API to pull info from Education.com site. I got all the school info, location info, etc. But how do I style it?!

I want to make a nice looking table, the output is like this:

```
<params>
 <param>
  <value>
   <array>
   <data>
<value>
 <struct>
  <member>
   <name>school</name>
   <value>
    <struct>
     <member>
      <name>schoolid</name>
      <value>
       <string>17914</string>
      </value>
     </member>
     <member>
      <name>schoolname</name>
      <value>
       <string>Fair Oaks Community High School</string>
      </value>
     </member>
```

Would I just use CSS or am I forgetting a step? I'm sorry for my ignorance.

Sincerely,
Carl

Comment: If I underst your question right, you want to use something like SimpleXML (this would be a good start: http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php, look at the examples) to traverse the result-xml and do something with the values. I hope it's just a snippet you've posted because otherwise it's not quite valid XML.

Comment: Yes sir, it's just a snippet. I'm not sure how to target the schoolname since everything is in a member parent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you can certainly write your own XML parser to build an HTML table the way you like it, this is one of the many things that [XSLT](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/) is good for. Some examples:

- [on AltaFHusssein](http://altafhussainbd.wordpress.com/2010/03/22/creating-html-table-layout-form-xml-using-xslt/) (now renders cleanly in Chrome)
- [on WROX](http://p2p.wrox.com/xslt/66523-create-generic-xsl-template-create-table.html) (old, but looks perfectly fine for what you're doing)

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect use for XSLT.  You can iterate over the elements in that XML and output it right into HTML.

This article details the needed steps pretty well.
http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/xsl.html